# Menu in left side don't appears with dropdown

Tags: menus, dropdown

Good evening,

I have a website in Wordpress that I have access to as admin recently. The menu is placed on the left side and when I try to create a submenu I wanted it to be in a dropdown but it only appears as a list ..

What can I do in the backoffice part?
Thank you